# Express command not found after setting installing globally

Tags: node.js, macos, express, npm, command-line

When I run `sudo npm install -g express-generator`:

```
/Users/myname/npm/bin/express -> /Users/myname/npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express-cli.js
/Users/myname/npm/lib
   └── express-generator@4.15.5
```

And when I run `express`:

```
express not found
```

Also, I thought it was interesting that when I run `which npm`:

```
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

That is the path.

It seems that whenever I try to install something like yeoman or this express generator globally, it never works.

It should also be noted that I am on an Mac running zsh.

Comment: [Try this](http://www.glatter-gotz.com/blog/2014/04/24/express-generator-on-osx-slash-homebrew-node-install/)

Comment: This sort of did the trick! Instead of changing it to /usr/local/share/npm/bin/ I changed it to export PATH=/usr/local/bin/npm:$PATH

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your npm bin directory is not in the path. Try to list the files in that directory by `ls -l /usr/local/share/npm/bin/`.

If you find the express file, you can add that directory to the path by `export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH`. If not, most likely something went wrong with your installation and you can try installing the module again.

Comment: Interesting. I posted the fixed below but I'm not sure why it worked. I also thought it was strange that express was posted seperately in the same directory. So /usr/local/bin/express

Answer (score 0):

Running this in the command line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/npm:$PATH
```

Fixed the issue...for now. I'm not totally sure why that worked.

Answer (score 0):

This affects `Homebrew` users using `Node.js` & `npm`

When you install `Node.js` using `Homebrew` it does not put `npm` on the `PATH` for you, however it suggests that you should do so.

> Homebrew doesn't modify the user's environment or dotfiles. However, brew install node does print a message suggesting the user add that path to their PATH.

[Source](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/21627)